# android right Intent FLAG

Tags: android

I have a problem to find the right FLAG. My objective is to start only oen activity but if I satrt a new activity, we have to this activity and finish other if it has already been started.

My workflow is :

startActivity A [situation 1] --> I receive a push and I startActivity A [situation 2].

So I want my activity A is finished and my activity A from the push is created again.

So I've tested with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` but (in my workflow) if I come back from situtaion 2 so I arrive to situation 1.
I've tested with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` but my activity A (in situation 2) is never start.

Thx in advance

Comment: why not just override `onNewIntent` and update your activity there when the new intent comes into that activity instead of recreating it

Comment: Because I'm lazy :). If I can't do it with Intent flag, i will do it with `onNewIntent()`